# OpenXML insert into content control Missing Word.Text

Tags: c#, openxml

I have written the following code to insert some text in a contentcontrol in the footer of a document.

```
oItem.File.CheckOut();
byte[] byteArray = oItem.File.OpenBinary();
using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
{
    mem.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length);
    using (WordprocessingDocument wp = WordprocessingDocument.Open(mem, true))
    {
        Boolean foundInFooter = false;
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = wp.MainDocumentPart;
        foreach (FooterPart footerPart in mainPart.FooterParts)
        {
            Word.Footer footer = footerPart.Footer;
            foreach (Word.SdtElement sdt in footer.Descendants<Word.SdtElement>().ToList())
            {
                Word.SdtAlias alias = sdt.Descendants<Word.SdtAlias>().FirstOrDefault();
                if (alias.Val.Value == "Revisionsnummer")
                {
                    foundInFooter = true;
                    if (sdt.Descendants<Word.Text>().FirstOrDefault() != null)
                    {
                        sdt.Descendants<Word.Text>().FirstOrDefault().Text = (string)oItem["Version"];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

for some reason sometimes the `sdt.Descendants<Word.Text>().FirstOrDefault()` return null so i cant insert text. Is there anyway in theese cases to add the Word.Text ?

Answer (score 0):

The premise of `.First/Single/OrDefault` is so that you can check the result of your expression prior to using it.  e.g.

```
var obj = sdt.Descendants<Word.Text>().FirstOrDefault();
if(obj!=null)
{
   obj.Text = (string)oItem["Version"];  
} 
else
{
   ...
}
```

If you automically try to assign a value to the result set of a `OrDefault` you will be setting yourself up for null reference exceptions.

Comment: My question maybe unclear, but what im asking is what should i put in else statment if obj == null to insert text to content control ?

Comment: it should be ok to do as i posted cause i check for null value first, but what do in else statement is my question hope you understand :)